# Swift: Sort Array with NSRange

Tags: arrays, swift, nsrange

I have an array with some `NSRanges` and want to sort them depending on their `location`.

```
var rangeArr = Array<NSRange>()
rangeArr.append(NSMakeRange(14, 4))
rangeArr.append(NSMakeRange(1, 3))
rangeArr.append(NSMakeRange(5, 5))
print(rangeArr)
```

...results in:

```
(14, 4), (1, 3), (5, 5)
```

But I need a result like:

```
(1, 3), (5, 5), (14, 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rangeArr.sortInPlace {$0.location < $1.location}
```